# how to pass nested hash params to searchkick

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am working on a existing rails app, where they are currently using `elasticsearch gem`. Now I am trying to switch it to `searchkick`. I have configured the gem on the app.
Currently if I do :

`Model.search(keyword)`  from the console, I am getting the out put.

But currently they are passing query string as a nested hash in the actual application, which looks like follows:

`{:query=>{:bool=>{:must=>[{:multi_match=>{:query=>"apple", :fields=>["title^2", "content", "description"]}}], :should=>[], :filter=>[{:term=>{:data_proxy_id=>"4d629f00-c8b1-aacc-97b5-e21e4c0bbe3f"}}, {:term=>{:article_type=>"Article"}}, {:term=>{:status=>"published"}}]}}, :sort=>{"_score"=>{"order"=>"desc"}}, :aggs=>{:group_by_section=>{:terms=>{:field=>"section.name.raw", :size=>0}}, :group_by_category=>{:terms=>{:field=>"category.name.raw", :size=>0}}, :group_by_author=>{:terms=>{:field=>"authors.fullname.raw", :size=>0}}, :year_based=>{:date_histogram=>{:field=>"publish_date", :interval=>"1y", :format=>"yyyy", :min_doc_count=>1, :time_zone=>"+00:00"}}, :month_year_based=>{:date_histogram=>{:field=>"publish_date", :interval=>"month", :format=>"MM-yyy", :min_doc_count=>1, :time_zone=>"+00:00"}}}}`

If I pass this hash as the params to `Model.search(query_hash)`. I am getting the following error.

`ArgumentError: unknown keywords: query, sort`

Answer (score 1):

Try with 
`Model.search body: {:query=>{:bool=>{:must=>[{:multi_match=>{:query=>"apple", :fields=>["title^2", "content", "description"]}}], :should=>[], :filter=>[{:term=>{:data_proxy_id=>"4d629f00-c8b1-aacc-97b5-e21e4c0bbe3f"}}, {:term=>{:article_type=>"Article"}}, {:term=>{:status=>"published"}}]}}, :sort=>{"_score"=>{"order"=>"desc"}}, :aggs=>{:group_by_section=>{:terms=>{:field=>"section.name.raw", :size=>0}}, :group_by_category=>{:terms=>{:field=>"category.name.raw", :size=>0}}, :group_by_author=>{:terms=>{:field=>"authors.fullname.raw", :size=>0}}, :year_based=>{:date_histogram=>{:field=>"publish_date", :interval=>"1y", :format=>"yyyy", :min_doc_count=>1, :time_zone=>"+00:00"}}, :month_year_based=>{:date_histogram=>{:field=>"publish_date", :interval=>"month", :format=>"MM-yyy", :min_doc_count=>1, :time_zone=>"+00:00"}}}}`

Comment: This returned zero records. Actually there are 15 records with the  `{:query=>"apple"`

Comment: I don't think this `body:` method will work for searchkick 2.5.0. I tried. And it's returning zero records.